# How to create testcase in angular to check value exist in local storage

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

My **component.ts** file

ngOnInit() {

```
if (localStorage.getItem('distanceUnit' + this.userMobile) == 'km') {
  this.toggleSlider = false;
}
```

}

setUnit(): void {

```
if (this.toggleSlider) {
  this.toggleSlider = false;
  localStorage.setItem('distanceUnit' + this.userMobile, 'km');
} else {
  this.toggleSlider = true;
  localStorage.setItem('distanceUnit' + this.userMobile, 'mi');
}
```

}

My test case is in **spec.ts file**

```
it('Toggle button should be false in case distance unit km', () => {
        component.toggleSlider = false
        expect(component.toggleSlider).toBe(false);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code for **localStorage** test cases.

```
 beforeAll( () => {
    let data= {};
    const myLocalStorage = {
      getItem: (key: string): string => {
        return key in store ? store[key] : null;
      },
      setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
        data[key] = `${value}`;
      },
      removeItem: (key: string) => {
        delete data[key];
      },
      clear: () => {
        data= {};
      }
    };
    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem')
      .and.callFake(myLocalStorage .getItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem')
      .and.callFake(myLocalStorage .setItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem')
      .and.callFake(myLocalStorage .removeItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'clear')
      .and.callFake(myLocalStorage .clear);

    localStorage.setItem('localStorageKey', 'value')
  })
```